# how to convert datetime with timezone to UTC datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime, iso8601

I have a string datetime as -
'2022-12-07T13:30:14+00:00' and '2022-12-07T13:30:07.697000+00:00'

How can I convert the `+` timezone to UTC time and get output in both the cases as -
"2022-12-07T13:30:14.000Z" and '2022-12-07T13:30:07.697Z'

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: No, its not the same input string

Comment: Are all your datetime strings end with +00:00 ? Or other offsets exist too ?

Comment: It can be any offset +05:30 also

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) and [isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat). If you have mixed UTC offsets, convert to UTC with [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone).

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

strings = ['2022-12-07T13:30:14+00:00', '2022-12-07T13:30:07.697000+00:00',
           '2022-12-07T13:30:14+01:00', '2022-12-07T13:30:07.697000+05:30']

for s in strings:
    print(
        datetime.fromisoformat(s)
            .astimezone(timezone.utc) # to UTC if input has other offset
            .isoformat(timespec="milliseconds") # consistent precision in output
            .replace("+00:00", "Z") # no "standard-way" to get Z for UTC
        )
    
# 2022-12-07T13:30:14.000Z
# 2022-12-07T13:30:07.697Z
# 2022-12-07T12:30:14.000Z
# 2022-12-07T08:00:07.697Z
```

Comment: will this convert work for '2022-12-07T13:30:14+05:30' to proper utc time?

Comment: @deepu2711 just added that; you'll need to convert then.