# convert datetime with timezone to proper format in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a variable

```py
date_1 = "2023-04-14T09:57:40-04:00"
```

how to convert to proper format - `2023-04-14T05:57:40Z`

Expected ouput - `"2023-04-14T05:57:40Z"`

Comment: Sorry, what 'type' of time is `04:00` at the end? Is it a minute? Hour? I'm not sure. Also what does the Z represent? I need it to provide an adequate answer. Thanks!

Comment: its utc timezone

Comment: @AnonyMous - See [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) / [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: @pp45 - Note, you've done the conversion in the wrong direction in your example.  `-04:00` means 4 hours _behind_ UTC. Thus the UTC hour is `13` (not `5`), because `13 - 4 = 9`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, you're looking to convert a date/time string with a UTC offset to UTC. You can do that like

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

date_1 = "2023-04-14T09:57:40-04:00"
utc = datetime.fromisoformat(date_1).astimezone(timezone.utc)

print(utc)
# 2023-04-14 13:57:40+00:00

print(utc.isoformat().replace("+00:00", "Z"))
# 2023-04-14T13:57:40Z
```

Notes:

- a UTC offset like -04:00 is not a time zone to be precise; multiple time zones can share the same UTC offset at a given time
- as Matt Johnson-Pint commented, UTC offsets are *subtracted* from the give time to get UTC, so *9 am* with -4 hours offset becomes *1 pm UTC*
- Python currently does not offer you to represent UTC as 'Z' when formatting to string, thus the `replace`
- [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module docs

Comment: Yep this solution does seem more appropriate and official. Please discard my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer to the other answer posted, this one does not properly convert UTC.**

```py
import datetime
import calendar
date_1 = '2023-04-14T09:57:40-04:00'
datex, timez=date_1[0:-6], date_1[-6:]
timed = datetime.datetime.strptime(datex, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
timez = datetime.datetime.strptime(timez.replace(':',''), "%z")
output=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(timed.timetuple()), tz=timez.tzinfo).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Code first splits datetime (`datex`) and timezone (`timez`). Converts `datex` to `datetime.datetime` then epoch, and convert `timez` to `datetime`. Finally converting `datex` to UTC time based off current timezone, then formats the `datetime.datetime` object to string.

Previous answer (not working)

```py
import datetime
import calendar
date_1 = "2023-04-14T09:57:40-04:00"
timed = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
output=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(timed.timetuple()), tz=timed.tzinfo).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

It's a bit long, but it should work!
The program first converts the `date_1` to a `datetime.datetime` object, then it converts it to epoch time, from which it converts this epoch time to the UTC timezone, and finally formats the epoch time to the output string.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Getting error - ValueError: time data '2023-04-14T09:57:40-04:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

Comment: I have a solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768770/how-to-convert-datetime-with-timezone-to-utc-datetime                                                                                   But its not working - AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'

Comment: @pp45 Give my edited answer a shot.